# Php Scandir to Mysql Which is Good Practice?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have file structure like below.

```
Ali
 --543
     --01.jpg
     --02.jpg  
 --544
 --545
Veli
 --002
```

Like this I have like 50 main folder and every main folder it has like 500 chapter folder. Every chapter folder it has like 30 images in it. I am gonna save this image paths and folder names to Mysql. And then from that saved data I pull out Json data for using wtih AngularJS. So which method keep my server less busy?

**Table A:** Every image path takes one cell.

```
name         folder    path
Ali          787        01.jpg
Ali          787        02.jpg
Ali          787        03.jpg
Ali          787        04.jpg
.             .             .
.             .             .
.             .             .
Ali          788        01.jpg
.              .           .
.              .           .
Veli         332       01.jpg
Veli         332       02.jpg
Veli         332       03.jpg
```

So I have thousands of images I dont think above method is not a good practice.

**Table B:** For this table in every chapter folder's images  take one cell. Which said not good practice. Which one should I prefer? Or any other suggustions?

```
name     folder      path
Ali       787       "01.jpg","02.jpg","03.jpg","04.jpg","05.jpg","06.jpg..........
Veli      332       "01.jpg"...................
Veli      333       "01.jpg","02.jpg"...........
```

**Wanted Json Output:** And How can I recieve Json output like below:

```
[
{
    "name":"Ali",
    "random": [
        {
            "folder": "787",
            "path": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
        },
        {
            "folder": "788",
            "path": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name":"Veli",
    "random": [
        {
            "folder": "332",
            "path": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
        },
        {
            "folder": "333",
            "path": ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Edit-1:

Ok I am gonna use Option B. Take look php code of mine  for the getting desired output.

```
$sqlx = 'SELECT name,folder,path FROM series';
$result = $dbx->query($sqlx);

$nArray = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
$nArray[$r["name"]][] = array('folder' => $r['folder'], 'path' => explode(",", $r['path']));
}
print json_encode($nArray);
```

Comment: Take option A. Option B involves aggregating data in a single column. SQL is not designed to handle data this way, and it will come back to bite you. A few thousand rows won't bother any current SQL implementation

Comment: Premature optimisation and all that....

Comment: Option A is better choice if you use indexing it will give you data in nano seconds from thousand or lakh record are present there and insert/update operation is also easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely have no need to query the database for individual images, and only ever intend to store strings you intend to replicate in the JSON data and nowhere else, then there's no harm in storing the folder aggregations in a single column, like you do in **approach B**. The underlying reasons for the good practice of not storing aggregate data in columns do not apply to the use case. But you might as well then simply store the ready JSON outputs there... (See comment below.)

However if you foresee the possibility of wanting to for example find folder(s) that have `image111.jpg` etc., whether in searching for duplicates, trying to locate the parent folder of an individual image, etc. you should definitely adopt **approach A** -- instead of trying to use something like `FIND_IN_SET`, or a more desperate `LIKE '%image.jpg%'`, in figuring out what image resides in whose which folder.

If you want the best of both worlds, insert all your file records per A, and then have a "cache" table per B that you call just for your JSON. That should make both the pragmatist and the idealist satisfied.

As far as the desired **JSON output**, you can easily generate JSON data with PHP's [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Simply feed in an array in a format that matches the desired JSON structure. You can easily "reverse-engineer" JSON data with [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). I fed in your desired JSON target output for a decode, and it would result from a `json_encode()` of the following array:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Ali',
    'random' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'folder' => '787',
        'path' => 
        array (
          0 => '1.jpg',
          1 => '2.jpg',
          2 => '3.jpg',
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'folder' => '788',
        'path' => 
        array (
          0 => '1.jpg',
          1 => '2.jpg',
          2 => '3.jpg',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Veli',
    'random' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'folder' => '332',
        'path' => 
        array (
          0 => '1.jpg',
          1 => '2.jpg',
          2 => '3.jpg',
        ),
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'folder' => '333',
        'path' => 
        array (
          0 => '1.jpg',
          1 => '2.jpg',
          2 => '3.jpg',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Result of `$json_array = json_decode($your_json_string); echo json_encode($json_array)` as below. You can use that to test your arrays. Same data, just less whitespace. (I've obviously added a few line breaks for readability; by default it's just a single chunk of a line that works the same.)

```
[
{"name":"Ali","random":[
    {"folder":"787","path":["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"]},
    {"folder":"788","path":["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"]}
]},
{"name":"Veli","random":[
    {"folder":"332","path":["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"]},
    {"folder":"333","path":["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"]}
]}
]
```

Comment: How many will nuke me from space if I mention storing serialized arrays or ready JSON strings into MySQL? :D It would definitely be the lowest-performance option, given the JSON would only need to be generated once when the directory is iterated for files, instead of on every call. You can use that for a cache, but certainly not for the main relational storage.

Comment: Ok thank you for the long answer:) I gonna take option B I think.  Could you look my edit for the php code part?

Comment: @Nasuh looks about right, that'd do it. Though if you do this, you're going to have to strip out the quotes surrounding the comma-separated filenames. Given that your filenames aren't going to have quotes to begin with (I hope!!), you might just as well plug them in as plain CSV.